# Why Integrate Redmine - Source Control Repository

Tags: redmine

What is the great motivation behind integrating Redmine with a source control repository ? If it is only for monitoring reason, developers already have access to repository and they can do whatever they want diff, history with their IDE. For other people do they really need? I'm afraid, I can't see the real reason. Can you please help me to see ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you fix a bug that exists in Redmine's issue tracker, you can refer to the issue id in the commit message and Redmine will automatically associate the commit with the issue (or even close the issue).
This saves you the double work of referring the issue in the commit message **and** closing the issue in Redmine.

By the way, this is not Redmine-specific - you can do it with most bug trackers that offer source control integration.

I don't remember the exact syntax in Redmine right now, but most of the time, the syntax is something like:

> fixes #123

...which would cause Redmine to automatically close issue #123, and create a link from the issue to the commit (and vice-versa).

Comment: I'd add that even if not closing the issue, just referring to it allows the commit message to appear on the issue detail. Therefore in redmine it's possible to see _on one page_ the issue detail, the redmine comments as well as what has been done about it.